# How to find domainid in Huawei Cloud?

Tags: huawei-cloud

How can we find domainID or account ID for calling APIs on Huawei Cloud?

The account name and account ID (domainid) are required for some URLs when an API is called. To obtain the account name and account ID, perform the following operations:

Answer (score 0):

The account name and account ID (domainid) are required for some URLs when an API is called. To obtain the account name and account ID, perform the following operations:

1. Register an account and log in to the management console.
2. Hover the mouse pointer over the username and choose My Credentials from the drop-down list.
   View the account name and account ID.

[image]

**More info:**
https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/devg-apisign/api-sign-provide-userid.html